# Webpack compiling vue with NODE_ENV=production still results in dev warning

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I run an extremely simple web pack config below against a vue.js frontend.  The bundle.js is compiled but still produces the 'You are running Vue in development mode' warning.  I have followed the advice specified [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/deployment.html) but it doesn't change anything.

Any ideas what's going on please?

This is my webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
entry: './www/src/js/main.js',
output: {
  path: "./www/static/js",
  filename: "bundle.js"
},
plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      NODE_ENV: '"production"'
  }
}),
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    compress: {
      warnings: false
    }
})
],
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: 'babel',
      exclude: /node_modules/
    },
    {
      test: /\.vue$/,
      loader: 'vue'
    }
  ]
},
vue: {
  loaders: {
    js: 'babel'
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Which version of Vue you are using? If it is **Vue 2.1.0 or higher**, check this answer:

Probably you are using the `vue.js` file instead of the `vue.common.js` file.

For direct use, you should use the `vue.js` for dev and `vue.min.js` for production. Both of these files has the environment hardcoded as 'development' and 'production', respectively.

For the WebPack, you should use the `vue.common.js` file instead, because it will handle the `process.env.NODE_ENV` variable. For this, add an alias attribute to your webpack file:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: You're right thanks.  Have updated my answer.  Not really sure why it makes sense to hardcode but sure there is a good reason.

Comment: Because someone could use the library without Node or without a WebPack/Browserify. For example, someone could just include the JS lib via a CDN, then the NODE_ENV variable would be broken.

Comment: If you are using SimulatedGREG/electron-vue this is exactly the setting you need to change!

Answer (score 11):

Issue was i was doing:

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js'
```

Instead of:

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
```

Difference being the first is hardcoded to dev which is why the warnings etc don't get stripped out.

Comment: These two imports are identical. Looks like one of them is wrong ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using OSX(Unix) || Linux

```
export NODE_ENV=production
```

Windows users should set the NODE_ENV using

```
set NODE_ENV=production
```

Are you sure you set your NODE_ENV var? Check for it.

```
echo $NODE_ENV
```